# How do I get an attribute from a Combobox and put it into a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I'm making a project in Tkinter Python and I want users to select an attribute from a `Combobox` widget and press a button and that attribute will be stored in a variable. I've searched all over the web, but I can't make heads or tails of the code and have no idea how to store this attribute. Can someone tell me how to do this

I've tried the `.get` thing... (module? widget?) but that is not working and as I said, the internet ain't no help.

This is my basic code with the window and the `Combobox`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()

ver = ttk.Combobox(master, state="readonly", values=["test1", "test2"]).pack()
Button(master, text="Run").pack()

master.mainloop()
```

I want to be able to store the selected item in the `Combobox` and put it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pack` returns `None` if you want to assign to a variable, you must do it on a separate line.
If you want action, `Button` requires a `command` key word arg to which you assign a callback.

After you have fixed the mistakes, you can use the `get` method on the `Combobox`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def print_selected():
    print(combo.get())


master = tk.Tk()

combo = ttk.Combobox(master, state="readonly", values=["test1", "test2"])
combo.pack()
tk.Button(master, text="Run", command=print_selected).pack()

master.mainloop()
```